# Youtube API - BadAuthentication despite correct login

Tags: oauth, youtube-api

I have an account with google which can login absolutely fine via www.youtube.com. However when I use the following code via the Youtube API:

```
$httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(

          $username = 'EXAMPLE@EXAMPLE.COM',
          $password = 'EXAMPLE',
          $service = 'youtube',
          $client = null,
          $source = 'EXAMPLE', // a short string identifying your application
          $loginToken = null,
          $loginCaptcha = null,
          "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");
```

I receive the following error: `'Authentication with Google failed. Reason: BadAuthentication'`

Why would I be able to login to google & youtube with the exact same credentials but not to the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you have enabled 2-step verification on your gmail account,
take note of the message at the top of this page:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps

Comment: 2 step wasn't turned on, however I enabled it and generated an application specific password for this service and it worked absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using clientLogin, witch is intended for installed applications, not web apps.
You should change this to AuthSub in order to get a token to make API calls.

That said, we have the same issue and we haven't change that (there's not enougth time to change aaaall auth changes in Google, Twitter and Facebook, isn't it?). The solution for us was to inform clients with that problem thet they have to disable the captcha by clicking this link and follow the instructions: http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

That's not the right way, but it's a way